# The topology produced by indexing subsets of a topological space.

Tags: general-topology

- Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ be a topological space.
- For each $A\subseteq X$, let $i_A:I_A\to A$ be an onto function.

Let's define:
$$f:\mathcal P(X)\to \mathcal P(X)$$
where $f(A)$ contains a point $x\in X$ iff any neighborhood $U$ of $x$, contains infinitely many $i_A(j)$, where $j\in I_A$.

- Let $f$ be a [Kuratowski closure operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms).

Does $f$ produce the same topology as $\mathcal T$?

---

> **Edit:** The above question can be extended to this more general
>   proposition:
>
> - Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ be a topological space.
> - For each $A\subseteq X$, let $i_A:I_A\to A$ be a function.
> - Let the function: $$f:\mathcal P(X)\to \mathcal P(X)$$ where $f(A)$  contains a point $x\in X$ iff any neighborhood $U$ of $x$,
>     contains  infinitely many $i_A(j)$, where $j\in I_A$;  be extensive:
>     $$(\forall A\subseteq X)(A\subseteq f(A))$$
>
> Then $f$ is a [Kuratowski closure operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms) which produces
>   $\mathcal T$.

Comment: what is $I_A$? The unit interval?

Comment: it can be any set. used for indexing.

Comment: and with infinitely many $i_a(j)$ you mean for infinitely many $j\in I_A$ not necessarily infinitely many points of $A$, I suppose?

Comment: yes‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.

Comment: But your $f$ is not necessarily a KCO, if $A=\{a\}$ and if $I_A$ is finite then $f(A)$ is empty.

Comment: we suppose it is a KCO (as an assumption).

Comment: Okay, then this implies that $I_A$ is always infinite and maps infinitely many points to each isolated point of a set $A$.

Comment: I think I have figured out that for each $A$ the closure equals $f(A)$. So $f$ is the normal closure operator.

Comment: OK. why don't you post your solution?

Comment: I'm entering it right now :-)

Comment: I think your edit is rather a restriction than a generalization. The new condition is sufficient, but it is far from necessary. As I said: Only an isolated point of a set need to have infinite preimage. Take $A$ and $I_A$ to be both the unit interval and $i_A$ is the identity. In fact, Extensivity is equivalent to "each open subset of $A$ has infinite preimage".

Comment: And if the space is $T_1$, then "each isolated point has an infinite preimage" is sufficient, since a finite open subset of $A$ is a union of isolated points of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in\overline A$. Let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x$. For each $a\in U\cap A$ this $U$ is also a neighborhood of $a$ intersecting $A$ in $U\cap A$. By assumption $f$ is a Kuratowski closure operator, so $a\in f(A)$. By the definition of $f$ we have $|i_A^{-1}(U\cap A)|=\infty$. This means $x\in f(A)$.

The other inclusion is trivial.

So $f$ is just the normal closure operator, hence it produces the given topology on $X$.

**Edit:** The only important property is the Extensivity, i.e. $A\subseteq f(A)$. This can be shown to be equivalent to the following: For each subset $A$ each relatively open finite subset $U\subseteq A$ has infinite preimage $i_A^{-1}(U)$. In a $T_1$ space we only have to require each isolated point of $A$ to have infinite preimage, since each finite open subset $U\subset A$ is a union of isolated points of $A$ in such a space.

Comment: it seems "Extensivity" and KCO are equivalent for $f$.

Comment: @CutieKrait: Yes, Extensivity is sufficient. Note that for $A=\emptyset$ the $I_A$ is empty, too, and $i_A$ is the empty map. Furthermore, $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ by defintion of $f$, we do not need to require it.